# DataTable Column.Expression Throw Error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

I Have Data Table which Contains Few row like below

```
CH1 CH2 Ch3 CH4 CH5
1   2   1   2   3
3   3   1   2   3
3   3   1   1   2
1   3   3   3   3
1   2   3   3   0
3   3   1   2   0
3   3   1   1   2
```

then I Try to add new column like

```
Dim col As New DataColumn("VCH1", GetType(Decimal),"(CH1+CH2+ch3)/CH5")
DtReadings.Columns.Add(col)
```

at that time give me error : Attempted to divide by zero. Because of CH5 have zero values,
but I need to add Dynamic Column with different Expression at run time ,how to avoid such type of error any Idea please Help.

Expression value not fixed,User Create expression for dynamic Column.
not only handle divide by zero error ,to handle all type of computing error

Comment: So what do you want to happen when you divide by zero?

Comment: Is this C# or VB question?

Comment: VB ,instead of zero or null

Comment: you can put a check on CH5, if it is null or 0 , replace it with 1, will it help ? so in case of 0 or null it will divide by 1 leaving the value of column = sum of column

Comment: Zero comes in any column and expression are not fixed,like "(CH1+CH2)/(CH3-CH4)"

Comment: then catch it in the exception

Comment: Thank you for all People,i have to found another Way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `DivideByZeroException` and then assign the value you want:

```
Try
    col = New DataColumn("VCH1", GetType(Decimal), "(CH1+CH2+ch3)/CH5")
Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
    col = New DataColumn("VCH1", GetType(Decimal), "0")
End Try

DtReadings.Columns.Add(col)
```

Comment: Not really sure that this will ever work. First I think the exception will be thrown at the Add time not at the building of the column, second the zero value is only in some rows and you try to add a default for the full column

Answer (score 1):

The [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) syntax allow the use of the IIF statement
You could build your DataColumn using this kind of syntax for the Expression

```
col = New DataColumn("VCH1", GetType(Decimal), "IIF(CH5 = 0, 0, (CH1+CH2+ch3)/CH5)")
```

Of course, being the Expression a string property you could build your expression dynamically based on the particular requirement you have at the moment. With IIF or ISNULL you could build your string on the fly before adding the column. Something like this pseudocode

```
Dim currentExpression as String = BuildCurrentExpression() 
col = New DataColumn("VCH1", GetType(Decimal), currentExpression)
```

Comment: The expression would be a little more complicate, since OP says that the formula is dynamic.

Comment: my Problem is Expression are dynamic,this is (CH1+CH2+ch3)/CH5 one of the e.g

Comment: I got the idea of mr. steve, but hopefully the OP get it `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create One Extension for Solve my Problem,that's take a time but i have no problem

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToCompute(value As DataTable, exp As String, inputColumn As String) As DataTable
    Dim tempdt As New DataTable
    tempdt = value.Clone
    tempdt.Columns(inputColumn).Expression = exp
    For Each row As DataRow In value.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToList
        Try
            tempdt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
            value.Rows(value.Rows.IndexOf(row))(inputColumn) = tempdt.Rows(0)(inputColumn).ToString
            tempdt.Rows.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            tempdt.Rows.Clear()
            value.Rows(value.Rows.IndexOf(row))(inputColumn) = 0
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next
    Return value
End Function
```